# SIGSEGV error when creating a new form

Tags: forms, delphi, lazarus

I have a main form with a `TMainMenu` and when I click on a submenu I have to show a new form. This is the code:

```
procedure TForm1.MenuItem12Click(Sender: TObject);
var Form2 : TForm2;
begin
 Form2 := TForm2.Create(nil);
 Form2.Show;
end;
```

And the in the `Uses` I put `Unit2`, which is the name of the 2nd form's unit. When I run the program, It correctly opens the Form 2. By the way, when I close the program I have a SIGSEGV error with Lazarus.

How could I avoid it? I have used this code too in other programs, but I had no problems. Both forms are setted on `FormStyle := fsNormal;`

[image]

Comment: Does it make a difference if you do it like this ? `with TForm2.Create(nil) do Show;`

Comment: No I still have that error...

Comment: What about ? `with TForm2.Create(self) do Show;`

Comment: It isn't the cause of your problem but it's generally not a good idea to use a local variable ("Form2") to hold an object whose lifetime may exceed that of the local variable.

Comment: @MartynA That's true if you need to refer to the form again in code. But if there is no need to do so then there's no problem with the local form var.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  Sure, but I was just thinking that if someone gets into the habit of doing that, the next thing they'll discover is an interface or other managed-lifetime thingie blowing up in their face when the local var exits scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem with the code you show is that you leak the form. You create it with no owner, and nothing else destroys it.

The obvious way to deal with that is to own it:

```
Form2 := TForm2.Create(Self);
```

This may not fix your error but it is the only thing wrong with the code you showed.

Comment: This is where I was going with my line of questioning

Comment: Since the OP uses `Show`, I wouldn't suggest using `Self` form as the owner. It the `Self` weren't a main form and would be closed, it will release the owned form which might be unwanted. `Application` is safer here.

Comment: @TLama Usually when one form opens another, the opener should be the owner. Certainly under windows you want the opener to be the popup parent. But it depends on the needs of this app. Certainly Application is possible too.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely causes is a problem in the OnFormClose event of Form2 -OR- a flaw in the destructor code of any objects on Form2.